# Rendering 2 scss and output them via Gulp?

Tags: sass, gulp

I'm new to Gulp, 
this Gulp setting is already rendered 'main.scss' but I want to add 1 more scss file named 'styles.scss' into this Gulp but kinda stuck. 
How can I insert this new scss ?
should I create a new task for new scss? well, I did but it seems that I'm doing it the wrong way.
how to add it in the correct way?

```
<pre><code> 

    "use strict";
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
      concat = require('gulp-concat'),
      uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
      rename = require('gulp-rename'),
        sass = require('gulp-sass'),
        maps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
         del = require('del'),
         autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
         browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
         htmlreplace = require('gulp-html-replace'),
         cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin');
    gulp.task("concatScripts", function() {
        return gulp.src([
            'assets/js/vendor/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js',
            'assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js',
            'assets/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js',
            'assets/js/functions.js'
            ])
        .pipe(maps.init())
        .pipe(concat('main.js'))
        .pipe(maps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/js'))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    });
    gulp.task("minifyScripts", ["concatScripts"], function() {
      return gulp.src("assets/js/main.js")
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(rename('main.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/js'));
    });
    gulp.task('compileSass', function() {
      return gulp.src("assets/css/main.scss")
          .pipe(maps.init())
          .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
          .pipe(autoprefixer())
          .pipe(maps.write('./'))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
          .pipe(browserSync.stream());
    });
    gulp.task("minifyCss", ["compileSass"], function() {
      return gulp.src("assets/css/main.css")
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(rename('main.min.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/css'));
    });
    gulp.task('watchFiles', function() {
      gulp.watch('assets/css/**/*.scss', ['compileSass']);
      gulp.watch('assets/js/*.js', ['concatScripts']);
    })
    gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
        browserSync.init({
            server: {
                baseDir: "./"
            }
        });
    });
    gulp.task('clean', function() {
      del(['dist', 'assets/css/main.css*', 'assets/js/main*.js*']);
    });
    gulp.task('renameSources', function() {
      return gulp.src(['*.html', '*.php'])
        .pipe(htmlreplace({
            'js': 'assets/js/main.min.js',
            'css': 'assets/css/main.min.css'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
    });
    gulp.task("build", ['minifyScripts', 'minifyCss'], function() {
      return gulp.src(['*.html', '*.php', 'favicon.ico',
                       "assets/img/**", "assets/fonts/**"], { base: './'})
                .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    });
    gulp.task('serve', ['watchFiles'], function(){
      browserSync.init({
            server: "./"
        });
        gulp.watch("assets/css/**/*.scss", ['watchFiles']);
        gulp.watch(['*.html', '*.php']).on('change', browserSync.reload);
    });
    gulp.task("default", ["clean", 'build'], function() {
      gulp.start('renameSources');
    });

</code></pre>
```

Any help really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: When you say  you want to "insert" another scss file do you mean just another file that gets compiled and  minified on its own or included into your main.scss?  Both are easy to do with some changes to your gulp.src's.

Comment: The main.scss is used to render some layouts, the styles.scss is going to be used for another layout. so I want the Gulp to render both compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming styles.scss is in the same folder as main.scss:

```
gulp.task('compileSass', function() {
          // src changed so that all .scss files in folder are used
          return gulp.src("assets/css/*.scss")
              .pipe(maps.init())
              .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
              .pipe(autoprefixer())
              .pipe(maps.write('./'))
              .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css'))
              .pipe(browserSync.stream());
        });

        gulp.task("minifyCss", ["compileSass"], function() {
          // same as above : gulp.src takes a glob of all .css files in css folder
          return gulp.src("assets/css/*.css")
             .pipe(cssmin())
             // name each file with the suffix, rest of name will be same as before
            .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/assets/css'));
        });

    gulp.task('clean', function() {
          // changed css item so all .css files are deleted
          del(['dist', 'assets/css/*.css*', 'assets/js/main*.js*']);
        });
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, Can you explain a little bit what's changed?

Comment: I edited it to add the 'clean' task modification too.

Comment: If you explain a little bit so I can learn from it too would appreciate it much

Comment: gulp.src takes something called a glob - one or more files.  Changing to "assets/css/*.scss" mean that all files ending with .scss are sent through the rest of the task pipes.   You should look a bit at the glob docs: https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob